# Как изменить свойство?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день! Скрипт обрабатывает атрибут со свойством translate. Как изменить его на margin?

```
$(function() {

var $win = $(window),
    $rev = $('[data-tr]'),
    winH2 = 0,
    winSt = 0;

function reveal() {

  winSt = $win.scrollTop();
  winH2 = $win.height()/2;

  $rev.each(function(i, el){
    var y = el.getBoundingClientRect().top,
        toMiddleMax = Math.max(0, y-winH2),
        idealMarg   = Math.min(+el.dataset.val, toMiddleMax),
        margMin     = Math.min(idealMarg, idealMarg * (toMiddleMax/winH2));
    $(this).css({transform: el.dataset.tr+"("+ margMin +"px)"});
  });

}
$win.on({
  "load resize scroll" : reveal
});

});

<div class="block" data-tr="translateX" data-val="300"></div>
```

Comment: приведенный скрипт не обрабатывает атрибут со свойством translate

Comment: но в коде _data-tr="margin-left"_ - поэтому вопрос абсолютно непонятен

Comment: То есть у тебя был код, работающий с margin, ты его сейчас меняешь под translate и спрашиваешь как его поменять под margin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разница, заключается в установке нужного свойства.

Для этого надо изменить следующую строчку

```
$(this).css({transform: el.dataset.tr+"("+ margMin +"px)"});
```

`margin-left` является непосредственным свойством, поэтому должно указываться вместо `transform`, и значение соответственно без использования *el.dataset.tr*

В итоге, для жесткого использования margin-left нужно его и указать

```
$(this).css({"margin-left": margMin +"px"});
```

Можно сделать более общее решение, если брать название свойства непосредственно из атрибута

```
$(this).css({[el.dataset.tr]: margMin +"px"});
```

Comment: @LADYX, например то, что IE пока не может в ES6, и в [вычисляемые свойства](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer). Просто собирай этот объект отдельно, а потом просто передавай в метод css

Comment: @LADYX, `var obj = {[name]: value}` <=> `var obj={}; obj[name]=value;`

Comment: @LADYX, смотри пример в комментарии выше и найди что именно отличается от твоего

Comment: @LADYX, ну если ты посмотришь на мой предыдущий комментарий, ты как раз это и увидишь _`var obj={}; obj[name]=value;`_